# Join two DataFrames by two id's Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am triying to join two dataframes with two id's.

Imagine that we have the next followings dataframes:

dataframe1 with the next fields: date1, id1, col1, col2, etc...
dataframe2 with the next fields: date2, id2, col'1, col'2, etc..

What I tried was the following:

```
pd.merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, left_on = ['date1', 'id1'], right_on = ['date2', 'id2'])
```

But I get duplicate rows.., I do not know how to solve it.

Keep in mind the following: the fields date1 and date2 are given by the year; and date1 has more years than date2.

How can I solve this code..?

Whatever you need, answer please.

Best regards.

pd:

That's what the dataframe's have in the id's.

```
dataframe1 = pd.DataFrame()

date1 = [2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016]
id1 = [2,3,1,4,2,1,2,2,1]

dataframe2 = pd.DataFrame()

date2 = [2015,2015,2015,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2018,2019,2020]
id2 = [2,2,1,4,2,2,34,2,1,3,3]
```

They have more fields, but they are all distinct and eliminated by duplicates.

Comment: Could you show a minimal data sample exhibiting the problem? As you describe a problem that should not occur, the question cannot be answered without that...

Comment: You likely have duplicated keys one one side. Check `df1[['date1', 'id1']].duplicated().sum()` and same for df2

Comment: @mozway I thought that It was duplicate rows in the dataframes, but I get the same thing..

Comment: @SergeBallesta, I have edited the question.., Do you need something more?

Comment: You have duplicates in both (id1, date1) and (id2, date2). How do you want to handle them?

Answer (score 0):

you can specify how to handle the duplicates using the `how` parameter in the pd.merge() function. There are four options for the how parameter : `Inner` join, `left` join, `right` join and `outer` join. Here's a link where you can find the definition of this for joins so you can apply one of them properly : [JOINS PANDAS](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/02/joins-in-pandas-master-the-different-types-of-joins-in-python/)

Comment: Hello, I just tried with inner and I get the same thing..

Comment: To handle the duplicates in your case, you can try using either a left join or an outer join, depending on which rows you want to keep. 
PS : the inner join is the default value of `how`